# ajax GET type not passing data to flask

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a method that tries to pass a variable to flask with the GET method. This is the code from jquery and flask:

```
    const impacttoolbtn = document.querySelector(".changingtoolbtn")
    impacttoolbtn.addEventListener("click", function (){
      $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url_for('impact') }}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(login_bool),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
      });
    })
```

where login_bool is true or false.

and flask:

```
@application.route('/impact', methods=["GET"])
def impact():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    print("hi")

    return render_template('/impacttool.html')
```

and I get "None" on print(data), while if I do POST on ajax instead of the default GET I get the right data I need. Any reason why this may happen? I would love some insights, thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

You have not defined the method type in ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "{{ url_for('impact') }}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(login_bool),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
      });
```

Comment: can you add login_bool in question and you can use `request.args.get("key_of_login_bool")`

Comment: hey! login_bool is just const login_bool = true; or false; I'll try that!

Comment: Do this `data:{"login_boo_var":login_bool}` and in flask `request.args.get("login_bool_var")`

Comment: hey, thank you for the thorough answers, now data sends to the backend, but im also running into this issue, where i have:

```
    data = request.args.get("bool")
    print(data)

    if(data == 'false'):
        print('test')
        return redirect('/login')
    else:
```

and its not redirecting to login, do you know by any chance why? Please and thank you

Comment: what have you passed in the bool in javascript, if you have used javascript false the try using `data == False`.

Comment: holy crap i finally got it to work, it was a ajax issue not redirecting in flask, i fixed it. Thank you